# mod_wsgi: "You can't open the application 'Xcode' because it may be damaged or incomplete."

Tags: xcode, macos, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to install mod_wsgi on my mac.
So I have installed Xcode command line tool.

```
xcode-select --install
```

And

```
sudo pip3 install mod_wsgi
```

it says following error.

```
error:command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
```

I already ask it on StackOverflow, I got answers I have to install Xcode command line tool. So I think something goes wrong with Xcode command line tool. When I click the Xcode icon, it says `"You can't open the application 'Xcode' because it may be damaged or incomplete."`
What should I do? I tried to reinstall Xcode but got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.
Graham Dumpleton helped me to solve this problem via another question.
After installing the `Xcode command line tool`, I installed `Xcode application` separately.That solved problem.